# Use of unresolved identifier PFFacebookUtils

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, xcode6, pffacebookutils

I've done all is mentioned here (https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#fbusers/iOS) for implement in iOS the Facebook Login.

The problem is that i have an compile error "Use of unresolved identifier PFFacebookUtils"
near che line

PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebook()

in AppDelegate. I've correctly imported the Parse and Facebook Framework into my project.
Are there some bug knowed in Xcode 6 Beta?

Comment: I have Parse working with Xcode 6. Maybe try using CocoaPods?

Comment: if using swift have you set up your bridging header and imported parse into it?

Comment: Yes, i've done it. Parse working fine, i've implemented a login user and its all ok. The problem appear when i use facebook login.

Comment: Resolved!

#import <ParseFacebookUtils/PFFacebookUtils.h> in bridging header,
Thank you!

Comment: This did the trick for me. You should add the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Parse docs doesn't mention this yet: After downloading the Parse iOS SDK, You should include the `ParseFacebookUtils.framework` into your project, then import it in each file you want to use it, like you did for the `Parse.framework` itself:

```
#import <Parse/Parse.h>// This use to be enough to use Facebook utilities
#import <ParseFacebookUtils/PFFacebookUtils.h>// But now we should import this framework as well to use Facebook utilitis
```

Parse team has separated the Facebook related classes from Parse API, hence a  `ParseFacebookUtils.framework`

Answer (score 1):

You may need to

```
import ParseFacebookUtils
```

in your AppDelegate

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use PFFacebookUtils or/and PFLogInViewController with swift, you have to do this:

1. For not V4 version:
   `#import <ParseFacebookUtils/PFFacebookUtils.h>`in bridging header and then `import ParseFacebookUtils` in swift file. And call `PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebook()` somewhere, of course best place for this is application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
2. For V4 version:
   `#import <ParseFacebookUtilsV4/PFFacebookUtils.h>` in bridging header and `import ParseFacebookUtilsV4` in swift file. And call `PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions(launchOptions)` in application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

Of course you should have set your bridging header correctly and import frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved! #import  in bridging header

Answer (score 0):

After the update to Parse/FacebookUtils, to import you do `#import <Parse/PFFacebookUtils.h>`