# No such module 'PFFacebookUtils'

Tags: facebook, swift, parse-platform, frameworks

I am getting **No such module 'PFFacebookUtils'** error on below line in my AppDelegate:

`import PFFacebookUtils`

I have checked and both `ParseFacebookUtils.framework` and `Parse FacebookUtilsV4.framework` are properly installed.

I believe my briding header is also working fine because I have 
`#import <ParseFacebookUtilsV4/PFFacebookUtils.h>` in it and there are no error there. I have other Parse frameworks installed and they are all functioning fine and their import statement have no errors.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: [Put `#import <Parse/Parse.h>` *before* importing the `#import <ParseFacebookUtils/PFFacebooksUtils.h>` in your bridging header](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25837377/use-of-unresolved-identifier-pffacebookutils).  You might want to try `import Parse` before `import PFFacebookUtils` in your Swift files, too.

Comment: @Michael: In my swift file, parse import is already before ParseUtils import. I also tried doing the same in bridging header but it seems that it does not matter what I do in bridging header. I am able to comment out everything in bridging header and still result is same.

Comment: Interestingly, if i remove `FBSDKCoreKit` from the project, it starts seeing PFFacebookUtils.h and starts showing me errors inside it like FBSDKCoreKt file not found etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by removing the line `import PFFacebookUtils` from swift file but leave the import in bridging header. Unless someone has a better answer?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any spaces in the name of your project? If that's the case you should head over to your Build Settings and find "Framework Search Paths". If you double-click on the tab with the name of your project (in my case "Project With Spaces"), you will see that Xcode has separated the project name to separate entries. You should remove the bottom entries that Xcode added (in my case "With" and "Spaces"), and change the actual entry (the one starting with "$(PROJECT_DIR)") to the project name - and here's the crucial part - but include a '\' before each space. That way, Xcode will keep the path as a single entry.

Before I made the changes:
[image: Before I made the changes]

After I made the changes:
[image: After I made the changes]

If your using any Libraries, you should do the same thing but to "Library Search Paths" instead.

Hope this helps!