# No such module "Armchair"

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, compilation, armchair

This problem is driving me insane. Whatever I do, I get the problem "No such module 'Armchair'" when I archive. It works when I build but when I archive XCode messes with me. I see XCode archiving/compiling Armchair.

- I have added `$(PROJECT_DIR)/AppName/External/Armchair/build/Release-iphoneos` to `Framework Search Paths`.
- I have added the framework in Embedded binaries
- I have added the framework in Linked Frameworks and Libraries
- I have also tried with adding the framework to copy frameworks in my `Build Phases`
- I have tried by adding the Armchair framework to my workspace instead and only added & coping the framework from there.

I think I have even tried a raindance, just to be sure. It keeps refusing to work when archiving, but works for normal building and running on device.

I have read and tried these related questions:

- [No such module 'PFFacebookUtils'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31038808/no-such-module-pffacebookutils)
- ["no such module" on Xcode 7 beta 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31106411/no-such-module-on-xcode-7-beta-2)
- [Cannot install Alamofire in new Xcode Project. "No Such module Alamofire"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25817479/cannot-install-alamofire-in-new-xcode-project-no-such-module-alamofire)
- [Getting error "No such module" using Xcode, but the framework is there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29500227/xcode-no-such-module-error-but-the-framework-is-there)

Running XCode 7.1. Any suggestions on how to solve it?

Comment: Can you post a dozen or so lines of the raw build output from just before the error message? Also, sanity check: have you checked the build logs to see what `$(PROJECT_DIR)/AppName/External/Armchair/build/Release-iphoneos` expands to during the build, and verified that the file actually exists?

Comment: are you using cocoapods?

Comment: @vinbhai4u I am in the project, but not for Armchair since they don't support Cocoapods.

Comment: @PaulCantrell I can pull out some stuff tomorrow and add it to the question. Yes, the folder does exists and so does the framework within it.

Comment: @PaulPeelen - have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29500227/xcode-no-such-module-error-but-the-framework-is-there

Comment: @Paul I've seen that one too. I've boiled it down to that something is wrong in my Pre-Release profile. Archiving using my "Release" profile works, running using "Debug" works as well... however archiving using "Pre-Release" doesn't. I can't seem to find what differs, but something does and I'll find it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. Its was too simple and kind of a stupid reason if you ask me.

My core app three configurations:

- Debug
- Release
- Pre-Release

The framework I added into my app, in this case Armchair, has only the `Debug` and `Release` configuration. 
When I archive my app, the Pre-Release configuration is used, which doesn't exist for the included `Armchair.xcodeproj`. Added the `Pre-Release` configuration to the `Armchair.xcodeproj` solved my problem.

Comment: Thank you SO much for this! I'm definitely filing a radar for this one. Almost went nuts trying to chase the reason for why one of our frameworks was archiving fine while the other wasn't.

Comment: For me the issue was with the auto-generated "Pods" project from CocoaPods. Adding my custom build configs here fixed the issue.