# Xcode No such Module

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift2, cocoapods

I am trying to use the `cocoapod` `Alamofire` in Swift. However, I get the error "`No Such Module`" when I `Import Alamofire` I am using Xcode 7.2 Alamofire 3.0 and Swift 2 The following are the steps I took

1) In terminal I ran

```
$ sudo gem install cocoapods
```

There were no errors then

2) I ran

`cd ~/Path/To/Folder/Containing/Project` (once in the project folder I ran)

```
pod init
```

3) Then

```
open -a Xcode Podfile
```

4) Then I added

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.0'
```

to the Podfile

5) Then I ran

```
pod 'Alamofire', '3.0'
```

followed by

```
pod install
```

I added `$(SRCROOT)` to `runpath` and `buildpath`.

Also I found this answer [No such module "Armchair"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33282475/no-such-module-armchair) saying to add the pre-release but I don't really understand how to do this or if this is my problem. Maybe this is obvious ,however I'm new to Swift and am not understanding.
Also should Alamofire show up in my frameworks, or pods folder? It isn't in either.
[files in project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqGKF.png)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After `pod init` you must use the new `<YourProject>.xcworkspace` instead of `<YourProject>.xcodeproj`.

The `xcworkspace` contains your `project` and your `pods` after `pod install`.

Comment: Ok thank you I feel dumb since it was such a simple solution somehow I couldn't find it. Thank You!

Comment: Everybody make this mistake. I also made when I using cocoapods for the first time.