# Import inside a Bridgind Header doesn't work for ParseFacebook in specific

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, parse-platform

I'm having a issue.

I followed the Facebook and Parse tutorials to implement login in swift, I have a error in this line, in my **Appdelegate.swift** :

```
PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions(launchOptions)
```

> **Use of unresolved identifier 'PFFacebookUtils'**

I have a working bridging-header, if I declare:

```
#import <ParseFacebookUtilsV4/PFFacebookUtils.h>
```

I'm still have the problem, but if I declare directly in my **Appdelegate.swift**:

```
import ParseFacebookUtilsV4
```

It solve the problem, I found the following post [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25837377/use-of-unresolved-identifier-pffacebookutils)

But this not solved my error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `Swift 2` frameworks have become more like modules, and thus you need to import them in class you're working in, rather than in the bridging-header. As you said, when you did that it solved your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.